# Resetting AUTO_INCREMENT is taking a long time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, auto-increment

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000000
```

This query is taking long time to update. Why? I need to optimize this query.

Comment: Why do you need this query? Looks like your table don't need an autoincrement primary key at all. What is the table structure and what is the purpose of such a reset? Anyway, rebuilding an index is always resource-consuming operation. I hope you need it not on the regular basis

Comment: Hi Sharpnel,
Thank you very 
much for your fast response.
In our website there are user generated data and admin generated data.  we are having huge number of users too.. 
        in this case if admin need to insert and update  bulk amount data and we don't want to clash the id's with the user data, so that we are reserving the id's by reseting the auto increment and using the same for insert and update in several tables. Since we are doing a bulk insert and update, we are writing the queries into a text file and doing it through command line

I hope you understand my problem. Please help

Answer (score 14):

ALTER TABLE causes a rebuild of the entire table - if your table contains many rows,this can take ages.

If you just need to bump up the value of the auto_increment value, the quickest way is to insert a dummy row (and then delete that roow if need be).  This will only take a fraction of a second, whereas ALTER TABLE can take days for a large table.

For example, suppose I have a table with an auto_increment ID column and other columns col1, col2...:

```
insert into autoinc_table set ID = 10000000;
delete from autoinc_table where ID = 10000000;
```

Comment: This didn't seem to fix my problem, which is that an int id field ran out of ids. Deleting rows didn't help on its own, and inserting a row didn't seem to trigger it to reset its auto-incriment value.

Comment: This trick only works if you want to increase the auto-increment value.  It sounds like you want to reduce it.

Answer (score 8):

user and admin data must be distinguished not by id, but by another field.
If you would treat an id as an abstract identifier with no other meanings it will save you a lot of time and resources, trust me.

Comment: Do you mean having another column such as `user_type` or having another table with a users catalog inside it?

Comment: @Pathros depends on your needs