# Reset auto increment value in mysql table

Tags: mysql

My mysql table auto increment value are like 83321, right now this value is 4110234543.

How can reset my old auto increment value?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql reset auto increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/mysql-reset-auto-increment)

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT`  by using the following

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 83321
```