# mysql auto increment error

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a simple

```
INSERT INTO t1 (fields...) (SELECT fields... FROM t2);
```

it inserts around 8.000 rows and the auto increment value of the table is set to ~16.000, but it's not exactly 2x as much. I don't include the auto incremented id in the query, and the tables are truncated. Can it be a bug? I have version 5.5.24.
Why is that, and how can I avoid this?

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` date NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `` (``),
  KEY `` (``),
  KEY `` (``),
  CONSTRAINT `` FOREIGN KEY (``) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `` FOREIGN KEY (``) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8440 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an initial insert to a new table or may there be some deleted records?

Comment: Truncating should work. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8e2/6)

Comment: yes I know, that's why it's weird for me, too.

Comment: have you checked the auto_increment system variables that are in the fiddle?

Comment: I have never seen this fiddle thing before, sorry... I don't really know yet what to do with it.

Comment: Never mind, you already answered in your other comment, that the auto_inc_offset and increment are set to 1. Could you provide a `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1`?

Comment: I guess I'll never find out why this happens, but I can do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/mysql-reset-auto-increment

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by your server's configuration (`/etc/my.cnf` for example):
You can set the `auto_increment_increment` and the `auto_increment_offset`.

If the first is set to `x`, you will have `(last_id + x)` for your next id.
If the second id is set to `y`, you start always with `y` (and then add `x`each time).

More probably: You just deleted all rows in your table and inserted again. This way the auto_increment value is not set to 1 again. You have to `TRUNCATE tablename` to reset this counter again (if you really want to delete all rows).

Edit:

Just saw your `CREATE TABLE` statement. If you really created your table with `AUTO_INCREMENT=8440` in the options, than of course, after inserting 8000 rows you will have an ID at 16000. If this is just a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` *after* the insert statement, I still don't know what's happening.

Comment: I have a basic wampserver config, I don't think there are any non-default `auto_increment_offset` or `auto_increment_increment` values set. Yes I have checked it and both are set to `1`.