# Mysql dump restore give abnormal error

Tags: mysql, magento

i am just stuck with some thing,
if some one kind enough to please get me out of this problem, 
i am moving a clients magento store from cpanel to AWS, i am not Mysql guy,

every thing went good, but when i import the sql file downloaded from the cpanel phpmyadmin,  and uploading to new server with mysql in shell,

it gave me this error,

*ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 44073: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT=358' at line 16*

and then i serched this in sql file and i find this strange syntax that is abnormal to me,
i am sharing the image of that block,
[image]

every thing is done, just this issue,

bundle of thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546949/mysql-auto-increment-error

Comment: bundle of thanks man,

Answer (score 3):

I tested with phpMyAdmin 4.2.5 and I confirm it fails to import.

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` table option (really, all table options) should appear before the `PARTITION` clause. This appears to be a bug in the way phpMyAdmin exports a CREATE TABLE statement.

You'll have to edit the export file and move the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in tables that have partitioning.

If you have a lot of data in the export file, it might be awkward to edit such a large file. If that's the case, it would be easier if you make two export files, one with data only and one with table structure only. Then edit the table-structure export. On the destination server, import the table-structure file first, then the data export file.

---

I logged a bug for this, we'll see what the developers say about it.

https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4487/