# How to reset autoincrement value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My company has different type of invoices.
Example:

H00001/2013
.
.
.
H99999/2013

and

T00001/2013
.
.
.
T99999/2013

The problem is, the numbering is increasing for new year.
How can I make auto increment value reset for each new year?

This is my current code:

```
    CREATE TABLE `invoices` ( 
      `invoicenumber` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
      `invoicetype` enum('A','B') NOT NULL, 
      `date` date NOT NULL, 
      `client` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (invoicetype,invoicenumber)
    ) COMMENT='' ENGINE='MyISAM';
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Answer (score 6):

Hey if you are using any client application for database like MysqlWorkBench or MYSQL Query Browser 
then you can do below steps to set AutoIncrement no -

- Right click on Table and go to Alter Table
- Select Options tab
- Under that you can find Auto Increment label there you can reset the number.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset auto increment value by using the ALTER TABLE statement. The syntax of the ALTER TABLE statement to reset auto increment value is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = VALUE;
```

**EDITED:**

If you don't want to run this query every year then you have other two option to do such thing as I am aware of this two.

1. Create cron job/windows scheduled job
2. As you are using **MySql** then there is [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) (Keep in mind this is added in MySql 5.1.6 not in previous versions of MySql)

Comment: do you mean i need to execute that SQL query every new year?

Comment: @user2862056 Yes, You have to run this query every year or there is other options like cron job or Event Scheduler.

Answer (score 4):

In your DB table, you can reset the counter with the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you already found a solution and the answer I'm giving may not be useful, since it's been seven months. 
 Returning to the topic, I noticed that you have a composed primary key with two columns (invoicetype,invoicenumber). **So there can be no duplicates of pairs *invoicetype,invoicenumber***  . **If you reset the auto_increment every year there might be possible to have duplicate pairs like 'A',1 for two rows, one invoice from year 2013 and the other from year 2014.** So you can eliminate that primary key to prevent the violation of the primary key constraint. You can instead define a primary key (any decent table has one) with an auto_incremented column to make every row unique. Then you can define an auto incrementation mechanism for the invoicenumber column (I will shall return to this issue). 
 First I would define the invoice table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `invoicenumber` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL, 
  `invoicetype` enum('A','B') NOT NULL, 
  `invoicedate` date NOT NULL, -- not recomended to use reserved words for column names like date
  `client` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT='' ENGINE='MyISAM';
```

Then I would define another table *list_id* :

```
CREATE TABLE `list_id` ( 
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `id_inc` int unsigned NOT NULL, -- number of invoice
  `the_year` date NOT NULL, -- year corresponding to the number of invoice
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) COMMENT='' ENGINE='MyISAM';
```

The above table can be used to set the value of *invoicenumber* for the current row inserted in *invoice* table (1 if it is the first invoice of the year of invoicedate, the maximum value of id_inc (coresponding to the year of invoicedate) plus one, otherwise). The rows are completed using a trigger of type *before insert* for the invoice table. So, before I insert a new invoice, I have to determine the value of invoicenumber. It will be 1, if there are no records in table list_id with column the_year having the value equal to the year of the new invoice. In this case I can insert in table list_id a new record with the values (1,2014) (id_inc,year). It will be the maximum value of id_inc plus 1, if there are record(s) in table list_id with column the_year having the value equal to the year of the new invoice. In this case I can insert in table list_id a new record with the values (7,2014) (id_inc,year). The trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `increment_or_reset_new_year` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `invoices` 
FOR EACH ROW
thisTrigger : begin
declare new_id_year int(11);
declare nr_invoices_year int(11);
declare new_invoice_begin int(11);
declare current_year_row int(11);


set current_year_row = year(new.invoice_date);

set nr_invoices_year = get_nr_invoices_year(current_year_row);

if(get_nr_invoices_year(current_year_row) < 1) then

set new.invoicenumber = 1;
insert into list_id(id_inc,the_year) values (1,current_year_row);
leave thisTrigger;
end if;

if(get_nr_invoices_year(current_year_row) >= 1) then
set new.invoicenumber = get_max_id(year(new.invoice_date)) + 1;
set new_id_year = get_max_id(year(new.invoice_date)) + 1;
insert into list_id(id_inc,the_year) values(new_id_year,year(new.invoice_date));

end if;
end;
```

There are 2 functions in the trigger. The first one determines the number of rows from the list_id table having the_year equal with the current invoice year (given as parameter):

```
create function get_nr_invoices_year(invoice_year int) returns int
begin

declare nr_invoices_year int(11);

select count(*) into nr_invoices_year from lista_id where the_year = invoice_year;

return nr_invoices_year;

end;
```

The second one determines the maximum value of id_inc from table list_id which has the coresponding value of the_year equal with the year of current invoice (given as parameter):

```
create function get_max_id(year_invoice int) returns int
begin

declare max_id_year int(11);

select max(id_inc) into max_id_year from invoices.lista_id where the_year =year_invoice;

return max_id_year;

end;
```

So I can have one trigger, two functions and one table which controls the incrementation of invoicenumber. 
Hope this helps! It worked for me!