# Reset auto increment for sql database in mvc 4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this might be a dumb question, but i want to reset my auto-incremented id column in one of my tables after I delete all the rows, how do i do that in a mvc 4 web app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: SQL Server, or what database?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to reset my auto-incremented id column in one of my tables after I delete all the rows

Use `TRUNCATE TABLE tablename` instead of deleting rows - that is much faster and resets the seed for you.

You *could* also execute the SQL command to reseed an auto-increment field:

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ("tablename", RESEED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server, you can run the command:

```
dbcc checkident(TableName, 'RESEED', 0)
```