# Return to 1 from autoincrement database field

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

Using SQL Server, I've got a column "ID" in my table that auto-increments every time I insert a new record.

How can I reset this counter and return to 1?

Comment: why are you trying to do this? the whole point of the ID is being unique........

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: @BartHofma possible example: you delete all rows from the table, and you want new rows to get id's starting from 1

Comment: Tagging this with only `counter` is really not clever.

Comment: ah, i got confused because he used "every time" so i thought he wanted to do it for each record. 
In your case the linked page should help

Comment: As an advice, never use auto-increment columns for ID. Instead on inserting values into the table use a procedure and you take care of the ID . For example set @ID = isnull(Max(ID),0)+1 from TABLE<-- this is a sort of replication for the auto-increment, but more eficient from my point of view

Comment: @CiucaS: _“this is a sort of replication for the auto-increment, but more eficient from my point of view”_ – and you are basing this statement on what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe based on experience.

Comment: @CiucaS: That is quite vague; without any actual prove I don’t think that statement can be supported.

Comment: @CBroe the differnce is that you don't have toreset the identity after every delete and also that will allow you to add your own values if needed.

Comment: @CiucaS: Auto-increment IDs _don’t_ get reset, and the usage of “own” values is normally also not a use case.

Comment: Suggested Duplicate goes to MySQL answer, not SQL Server ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are SQL Server, and assuming your ID column uses [the IDENTITY() property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx),  you need to use the [DBCC CHECKIDENT syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx):

```
USE MyDatabase
GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('myschema.MyTable', RESEED, 1); 
GO
```