# Reset Auto_Increment on MySql via MSSQL? I'll even settle for Truncate

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL Server 2008 R2 system that updates various tables on various systems during a nightly process. I have a MySQL linked server that has an Auto_Increment on one of it's tables. This tables contents are deleted and replaced each night. This of course does not reset the increment. I have tried:

```
 ALTER TABLE REMOTEMYSQL...[TableWithAI] AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

And I get:

```
 Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'
```

I can successfully:

```
 delete from REMOTEMYSQL...[TableWithAI]
```

But obviously that doesn't reset the increment on the MySQL side

I tried:

```
 Truncate TABLE REMOTEMYSQL...[TableWithAI]
```

and I get:

```
 Cannot find the object "TableWithAI" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

But the MySql user that is used in the link has full permissions. How can I ether delete the contents and zero the increment, or zero the increment by itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. That question is asking how to reset from the MySQL side. I am on MSSQL via a linked server connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your MySQL already configured as a linked server, you can [fire off non-query statements to linked servers with `EXEC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
EXEC('ALTER TABLE TableWithAI AUTO_INCREMENT = 1') AT LinkedMySQLServerName;
```

I believe the query should be in MySQL syntax, but I'm not in a position to test from where I'm at.

Comment: I had to go in and set up RPC, but it worked! Thanks!