# MySQL - ID issue

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

The basic problem, I have a column called 'ID' which is set to AUTO_INCREMENT and PRIMARY index.

If I add a row it sets the ID to 1, next row to 2, etc. It's working fine.

But when I have for example 6 rows with IDs: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and I delete row with, for example, ID = 6, so it's: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` now, and I add a new row, it doesn't get ID = 6, instead ID = 7. So it's: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7`. What's t he problem?

Why do you downvote my question? I just wanted to know...

Comment: No problem, it is how `auto-increment` is designed.

Comment: Maybe you could use this in some way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql :)

Comment: Oh I see. So it's supposed to work like that? Haha :D

Comment: You should never design any system so that it's dependent on consecutive primary key values, only on unique primary key values

Answer (score 0):

The autoincrement (AI) column is supposed to behave that way. The running count of the AI becomes part of the table definition.  You can run `show create table "yourtablename"` and see that after the `Engine` definition there will be an AI count.

You can run `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;` to set the AI back to 6 if you delete the 6th row. Although, this is not recommended.