# Reset id in the database

Tags: database, reset

I have a database and 1 table with a list of users.

Everyone has their own id.

When I delete all users and create a new user the id is automatically is set to 30

Before I deleted the last user was 29.

How do I reset it so when I create a user it resets to 1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

This question is too general as it depends on the database. However, the most likely answer is probably:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

See this post for more deets: [How to reset AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)