# Using Auto incrementing ID as primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm making a basic blog. The user can add a post, filling in title, body, date. When submitted, the primary id field will obviously auto increment.

I'm using Laravel 5 seeding to populate the database with dummy data. The issue is, when I need to reseed data, I delete the prior rows, `DB::table('articles')->delete();` then reseed.

The problem is, the autoincremented `id` continues from the last `id`. So If I'm seeding 10 rows on initial migrate, I get 1 thru 10. No problem. If I reseed, I get `id` 11-21.

This is problematic because I'm accessing the articles by ID, `http://localhost/article/1` (`Route::get('article/{id}'...`) but there obviously is no longer an ID of 1. The first article ID is now 11.

To get around this, I created a second `id` column called `article_id`: `$table->primary('article_id')->unsigned();` as primary key so Laravel would query that.

- This causes problems now because on article insert, I need some way to auto increment the ID.
- Having a second `id` column seems unnecessary and bad way to make a schema

I'm sure this is a common issue- I'm wondering how to get around this.

Comment: One way would be resetting the auto increment id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: I cannot see why this is a problem. But TRUNCATE will reset the AI.

Comment: @Strawberry `http://localhost/article/1`, if there is no article with `id` of 1 in DB, then I get a `ModelNotFound` exception.

Comment: @Growler As you should. Why does it matter? Users don't navigate your site by randomly picking item IDs.

Comment: You return an array. Just select the first item in the array.

Comment: @ceejayoz what If I am testing the response of a given article. It's easier to do `article/1` everytime and expect article 1 then `article/310` as article 1.

Comment: If it's just for testing, `DB::table('articles')->truncate();` will blank it out and reset the ID. Just make sure it can't be called in production.

Comment: @ceejayoz exactly what I was looking for. Post as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('articles')->truncate();
```

will delete the entire contents of `articles` and reset its increment ID.

For obvious reasons, make *very* certain this can't be called in production. :-)

Answer (score 1):

in your PHP when you want to reset auto increment id than just execute this command as you execute select or insert or any other sql command in PHP

```
   ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Although these values are being created automatically, MySQL does allow you to explicitly set values for them. In other words, if you're migrating a table you don't need to worry about the keys being automatically created in the correct order with the appropriate gaps, you can simply write the values in your insert

```
CREATE TABLE t_autoinc1
(
   c1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 );

 -- 0 or NULL means that next ID will be generated by MySQL automatically

 -- inserts 1
 INSERT INTO t_autoinc1 VALUES (0)
 -- inserts 2
 INSERT INTO t_autoinc1 VALUES (NULL)

 -- inserts 100, not 3
 INSERT INTO t_autoinc1 VALUES (100)

 -- inserts 101
 INSERT INTO t_autoinc1 VALUES (NULL)
```

See this answer in the MySQL forums http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?60,499281,503603#msg-503603