# How can I automatically reset AUTO_INCREMENT every time the database is clear?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm kind of new to MySQL, truncate, and id ... and I'm trying to learn it.

I have a table with **4** objects/rows. 
I list all of their ID like this.

I wish them to have the id of : 1,2,3,4. But this is what I have right now :

[image]

I tried to clear out my table and re-construct it back, but my ID doens't seem to start from 1,2,3 and so forth.

How can I make them start again from 1 every time the database is clear ?

Is there anything that I can tweak on my table, MySQL, or even within my Laravel application to achieve something like this ?

Comment: `truncate table_name` should do the job

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql  you need to reset the auto increment.   Less drastic that rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: Where/When should I do `truncate table_name` ?

Comment: Use truncate to completely wipe the table. If you just delete a bunch of rows, the index won't reset. And make sure your id is set to Auto Increment. Edit: That's good.

Comment: @TimLewis : I had mine set to auto increment.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` Is that right ? If  I run this, will it wipe out my data ?

Comment: @rangerover.js... just running that will most likely cause conflicts if you haven't removed the rows...

Comment: On a side note, try not to worry too much about your indexes... Yes everyone likes 1, 2, 3, 4, etc instead of 1, 3, 6, 9, etc, but in a database, you should just worry about the actual data and not it's indexes (unless you somehow get two of the same index, then there`s a **real** problem).

Comment: Just as @AbhikChakraborty, you should use `truncate table`, docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: If you care about the values, then something has gone very wrong somewhere!!!!