# insert a row with one column value based on last record

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert a newly added product in table. But to do so I need to check SKU of last inserted product and increase it by 1 and insert it with new product details. SKU is something like SKUNXXXXX - X is a digit. Changing table structure is not possible.

Possible solutions that I can think of is

- Get last row using order by and limit 1.
- replace "SKUN" with empty string and increase the number by 1
- Insert record with product details and incremented SKU value

But this situation may create a problem(though I am not sure about it).  Problem is - what if just after fetching last record and before inserting the new product details, another request comes in and gets the same last record? In this case both of the products have same SKU.

Please let me know how to solve this situation.

Comment: in this case, may be, u should use table locking or transactions

Comment: Why don't you use an auto-increment column instead of a character string?

Comment: @Barmar - I know auto-incremented column is the best way but I can't change it know as previous developer has used it in many places and it will break things. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Then use a transaction like @M0rtiis said

Comment: BTW (about previous developer) its not a big deal to do AI there. use fulltext search on your project and change things, +1 sql migration

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an auto increment `id` column and then use this to create the `SKU` for each product as it gets inserted.  A trigger, which would fire after an `INSERT`, could then be used to assign the `SKU` for the newly inserted product.  But alas, MySQL does not allow a trigger to modify the table which fired it.

However, there is a potentially easy workaround here.  If your `SKU` values will really always have the format `SKUNXXXXX`, where `XXXXX` is some number, then you can simply add an auto increment column, and create the `SKU` value on the fly when you query for it.  So you might create a table called `products` with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(55),
    ...
);
```

Everytime you do an `INSERT` on `products`, the `id` column will automatically be incremented by MySQL.  When you want to get the `SKU` out, you can simply do a query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, CONCAT('SKUN', id) AS `SKU`
FROM products
WHERE name = 'someproduct'
```

If you want the `SKU` number to not be forever (i.e. once assigned to a given product, it can be reassigned to another new one), then you might consider resetting the auto increment `id` column, q.v. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql) for more information.