# Is there a way to stop increasing the auto increment value in mysql when running specs?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rspec, sinatra, datamapper

I have about 100 specs, In a Sinatra project I'm currently developing.
For testing I'm currently using rspec + DatabaseCleaner with the :transaction strategy.

Some of those specs require creating new records in the database and thus they increase the auto increment table value in mysql. Is there a way I can run my tests with the transaction strategy, without increasing the auto increment value using DatabaseCleaner or another gem?

Edit: I would like for auto_increment to have the value it had before the tests ran.

Comment: what value you want in your auto_increment column....

Comment: @ZafarMalik The value it had before the tests ran.

Comment: If you are passing your own id in auto_increment column then it will take your own passed value instead of auto_id...so you don't should be worry for it...but make sure that id should not exist in table...if you are trying to say something else then please clear.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I'm not pasing an ID to auto_increment. When my tests run some of them insert records into the DB and then they are deleted, however the auto_increment value doesn't roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that at the time of test no record will insert from production or outside test.

First get last auto_id from your table by below command-

```
select max(id) from mytable;
```

Suppose it was 240125

Now start your test and after completion your test do as per below-

First delete all newly created auto_ids-

```
delete from mytable where id>240125;
```

Now set auto_increment from this possition.

```
alter table mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=240126;
```

Comment: This looks good. Is there a way It could be done only for the tables that had insertions?

Comment: as you can set auto_increment value at table level so its on you for which table you want to reset auto_increment....in your case...you can find out tables where you think insertion will be done....you can also automate this process by stored procedure suppose before your test save max auto_id in a temp table...then store same id after your test...and compare where 2nd id > 1st time stored id then delete all records more than 1st time insert ids only tables where 2nd id > 1st id and reset auto_increment id = 1st time saved id + 1....

Answer (score 2):

Reset the value to some known value after tests. Have a look here...

[How to reset AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)