# Autoincrement not working properly in table

Tags: mysql

I created a table `department` with 4 columns and set `deparmentid` column to autoincrement. Now, after deleting 8 records out of 10, on adding the new record the value of `departmentid` is shown as 11 instead of 3. I truncated the whole table but again it is showing the same result on inserting the data. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the counter with:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

For InnoDB you cannot set the auto_increment value lower or equal to the highest current index.

Comment: Welcome.You can mark my answer as correct.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how auto increment is working. It doesn't matter if you delete from the table. If you want to change the auto increment id you need to run

`ALTER TABLE department AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;`