# Why do my sql tables maintain deleted id's?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I insert data into a brand new table, it will assign a new id via AUTO_INCREMENT.  So the first time I perform an insert I get an id of 1.  However, if I delete the row and insert new data, the table acts as if there is still a preceding row (the new row will have an id of 2).  This behavior concerns me because I feel like the data is still persisting somewhere.  Any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: You aren't alone in feeling that data is persisting. When I started working with databases, I felt the same way. Once you work with auto_increment fields enough you will get in the habit of doing `select id, name...from tablename order by id`. If you notice ID 1, 3, 4...you can conclude that id 2 was deleted. In some cases you will have to archive deleted data, which makes it easier to see what got deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not persisting. MySql maintains a separate table about your table containing, among other things, the next auto-increment value for your table. You can reset this with:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

However, be aware that if you are resetting to a value below another valid value in the table, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: How can I access that information?  I'd like to start from id=1 every time I empty the table (the only reason I'm emptying tables is for experimentation and learning purposes).

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw - See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql) for more info. But just use the `ALTER TABLE` statement like I suggested whenever you empty the table.

Comment: You can do `truncate table tablename;` and then `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;` to reset auto increment to 1

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the swift assistance!  I'll definitely avoid resetting the id to 1 if any data exists in the table.

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw - Also, it never hurts to consult [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). :)

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes.  You were too fast! haha.

Comment: I'll definitely continue to read up on the documentation.  "The pros always practice the basics."

Comment: @j3ssi3ftw it's a very common tendency to want your IDs tidy, but it will help you if you can get it into your mind that `AUTO_INCREMENT` values -- also known as surrogate keys -- have no intrinsic meaning, and good database practices include the fact that they should not be imbued with meaning.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I agree in general. There may be exceptions, though, for things like running test cases.

Comment: True, @TedHopp. +1

Answer (score 2):

you should simply use.

```
truncate table tablename;
```

Comment: Just for OP's consideration: truncate table will reset auto_increment field to its start value: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: One problem with `truncate table` is that it won't work on InnoDB or NDB tables if any foreign keys in other tables reference the table. It also doesn't invoke any `ON DELETE` triggers. Otherwise it's pretty much as good as (and faster than) deleting all the rows and altering the table's `AUTO_INCREMENT` value explicitly.

Comment: I just looked up an example for truncate, it's extremely useful, but thanks for the heads up on the exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, even if the child FK's are empty, truncate won't work.