# Numbering the array rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have selected the whole table with mysql, there are records of sold tickets.
When I am writing them out with foreach, they are showing correctly from the newest sold ticket at the top to the oldest purchase at the bottom.
The problem is that the IDs do not look good. I have done many test purchases before launching it and the id numbers are starting from 50 now.
I would like to keep it as it is now but only number the records with normal numbers from 1. The problem is that the highest number must be at the top since the latest record is there on top. Could somebody advice me on how to do this please?

Comment: Please let me know if any of the above is not clear enough

Comment: You have to make DESC through ID query and show the serial number with new generated variable.

Comment: Do you want to reset the ID's to start from 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset AUTO\_INCREMENT in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: the answer above is correct, that's wat you want, you may also drop the table and recreate it

Comment: You should always add your code for best help/assistance. I've added a snippet below that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use while loop you have to create one variable before start loop and increatement it by 1 in loop and use it as row number :)

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM  tbl_purchases ORDER BY id DESC";
if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    $line_counter=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>".
                "<td>{$line_counter}</td/>".
                "<td>{$row['id']}</td/>".
                "<td>{$row['name']}</td>".
             "</tr>";
        $line_counter--;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Yes but the numbers will go from 1 in the top of the list and will be increasing to the bottom. But the top row is the latest purchase so it has to have the biggest number. It is difficult to my brain haha

Comment: I have modified answer :)

Comment: Oh I couldnt figure out what will be the biggest id number but i can just count the rows and decrease with each loop. Thats brilliant haha. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

to display with custom index in descending order using php

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM  tbl_purchases ORDER BY id DESC";
if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {
    $index = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>".
                "<td>{$index}</td/>".
                "<td>{$row['id']}</td/>".
                "<td>{$row['name']}</td>".
             "</tr>";
        $index--;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

for ascending index

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM  tbl_purchases ORDER BY id DESC";
    if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {
        $index = 1;
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<tr>".
                    "<td>{$index}</td/>".
                    "<td>{$row['id']}</td/>".
                    "<td>{$row['name']}</td>".
                 "</tr>";
            $index++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

==================

To reset the auto incremental column in DB (start again from 1)

For MYISAM

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_purchases AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

For INNO DB

```
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE tbl_purchases SET id = @num := (@num+1);
ALTER TABLE tbl_purchases AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you're fetching from DB, the ID column which is usually on auto-increment is not reliable, so when fetching, you should run your own auto-increment. i.e.

```
<?php foreach($rows as $index => $row): ?>
    <table>
      <td><?php echo $index + 1 ?></td>
```