# mysql load data infile auto_increment mutiple incrementation

Tags: mysql

while executing same file multiple times the auto incrementation value will be wrong.
my file is sample.csv

```
name,phone,address
a,9401003026,dsa
b,9658746542,fsa
c,9865742310,hgfh
d,9865869537,hf
e,9401003026,hf
s,9658746542,hf
h,9865742310,hf
j,9865869537,hf
```

and my query is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/anson/AnsonBackup/python/newtest/sample.csv'    
           INTO TABLE `sample`  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','  
           LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
           (named,phone,address);
```

if i excecute one time the value of id will be 8 but when i reexecute the same file the id starts from 16..why????

my table is

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `named` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: i tried this SQLyog community - MYSQL GUI v 11.27(64 bit)   (c) 2001-2013 Webyog Inc

Comment: when i excecute the file at once  the last id value will be 8 and its auto_increment is not 9.it displayed as 16 and  when i reexecute the same file the id starts from 16..why????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got an answer

we must change its ENGINE from INNODB to MyISAM

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `named` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, never depend on auto_increment columns to have certain values, as the same issue you describe can happen. The id gets increased every time you insert in the table.

If you need to, you could include the id field in the csv also, so your import sentence would be:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/anson/AnsonBackup/python/newtest/sample.csv'    
       INTO TABLE `sample`  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','  
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES 
       (id, named, phone, address);
```

Or, if you can't do that, you have to reset the counter, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

With the correct auto_increment you need instead of 1. More info about that here: [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: i must be need to depend on auto increment. i cant pass the id like this (id, named, phone, address);

Comment: if i use the ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; i must be execute this value each time(more than one time) for my file execution