# MySQL auto increment starts from 4

Tags: mysql

I'm using Workbench. In MySQL auto increment starts from 4 and then increase on 10 each time and I can't do nothing whith it.

Comment: It is impossible to solve your question without providing more details. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

That could be cause, someone have reseed the `auto_increment` in which case it will start with the specified value like below, where `auto_increment` field will start with 100 instead of 1. See [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more nformation on the same.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

Again, by default the increment counter is 1. That is every new `auto_increment` value will be incremented by 1 but that can be configured as well using the `auto_increment_increment` configuration settings.

See [InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT Counter Initialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization) for more information on the same

Per [Documentation On sysvar_auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) you can set it like below:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';

mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the table if possible, then run the following two queries and create the table again.

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=1;
```