# how to delete id of deleted rows in sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net

After I delete all values in table in sql and add new set of values, the id for new values keep showing cumulative of the deleted values. How do I start from 0 id and not cumulative of the deleted values? Please help.

Comment: You could do something like:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: Using MS SQL you can use the TRUNCATE statement the delete the whole table and let the identity start back from 1.

Comment: @Kevin how do i do that without deleting the whole table? thanks.

Comment: @Sonam what you're suggesting actually sounds like bad practice. I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reseed the identity without using TRUNCATE you can use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('<YourTable>', RESEED, 0);
GO
```

First execute the DELETE statement and then run the DBCC command.

For more info: [Mircosoft MSDN DBCC CHECKINDENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database you are using.

For mysql for instance you could use:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

to reset the counter