# How to drop auto_increment from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

this should be a very easy issue but I couldn't find a solution that works.

I migrate the date from Oracle to MYSQL and during the process, all primary keys were set to auto_increment.

However, there are a lot of identified relationships (parent PK is the same of children).

So the correct way to do the transaction is to insert into the parent tables, get `result.insertId` from this interaction and then insert the same value in the child table. I know that I could simply ignore the auto_increment sending the id in the insert command but I didn't like to just let this go.

As the solutions I read about say that I need to change the column to the exactly the same specification but auto_increment, I run the following SQL:

```
alter table added_object modify column id_interaction_object int(11) not null;
```

.. And I get the following message:

> ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'id_interaction_object': used
>   in a foreign key constraint 'FK__METRIC__ADDED_OBJECT' of table
>   'metric'

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: In the future, I know you're a bigger pro than me, but that statement should be written like this: ALTER TABLE added_object MODIFY COLUMN id_interaction_object INT(11) NOT NULL;

Answer (score 34):

You need to disable foreign key checks:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

alter table added_object modify column id_interaction_object int(11) not null;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! What about the best way to reset the value of the auto_increment in the tables that will continue with auto_increment?

Comment: @Encoder What do you mean? Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot :) @PaulSpiegel