# Add auto_increment feature to a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem related to sql language.
I am trying to add the auto_increment features to a pre-existing row with the primary key attribute. What I get back is :

**Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'ODB_ID': used in a foreign key constraint target_ibfk of table 'test3.target'**.

The statement used for the table was

```
CREATE TABLE `Receptor` (
  `ODB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Older Name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Uniprot_ID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Organism` enum('H','M','R') NOT NULL,
  `Sequence` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ODB_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And this table refer to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `Target` (
  `Pubchem_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ODB_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Receptor` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `EC50` decimal(6,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reference_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `Pubchem_ID` (`Pubchem_ID`),
  KEY `ODB_ID` (`ODB_ID`),
  KEY `Reference_ID` (`Reference_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `target_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Pubchem_ID`) REFERENCES `general` (`Pubchem_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `target_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ODB_ID`) REFERENCES `receptor` (`ODB_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `target_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Reference_ID`) REFERENCES `publication` (`Reference_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I have tried with the following commands plus from the MySQL gui:

```
alter table `Receptor` MODIFY `ODB_ID` int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;
```

```
alter table `Receptor` CHANGE `ODB_ID` `ODB_ID` int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;
```

I viewed another suggestion on the site, but it doesn't work for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606469/cannot-change-column-used-in-a-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: OT note: On some systems table names are case sensitive and `receptor` is not the same as `Receptor`. So please be consistent to avoid problems when you decide to migrate your DB to another system.

Comment: Related: [How to drop auto_increment from a mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087283/how-to-drop-auto-increment-from-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable [`FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks). Then enable it again after the operation. The following works for me:

```
set session foreign_key_checks = 0;

alter table `Receptor` MODIFY `ODB_ID` int not null auto_increment;

set session foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64s5pALa8nzmXkjB5y4WZy/0)

Note that I also removed `PRIMARY KEY` after `auto_increment`, since ODB_ID is already the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Receptor MODIFY COLUMN ODB_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I believe that the auto_increment column must be part of the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY, so if that does not work, try:

```
ALTER TABLE Receptor MODIFY COLUMN ODB_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```