# Auto Increment From A Six Seven Number

Tags: php, mysql

I know this may seem like a similar question out there, but it really is not. I am trying to create a seven digit ID number that is saved in my mySQL database.

I'm using this `sprintf("%07d", $idNumber);`

This works, and creates a seven digit id number. However, I want to insert this into my database. The problem is I don't know how to increment this ID number then insert it into the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a column with the `ZEROFILL` option, and then insert unformatted integers.

```
mysql> create table foo (id int(7) zerofill auto_increment primary key);

mysql> insert into foo values (123);

mysql> insert into foo () values ();

mysql> select * from foo;
+---------+
| id      |
+---------+
| 0000123 |
| 0000124 |
+---------+
```

This is the *only* time the numeric argument to the `INT` type has any practical use. I wish they had made the argument on the `ZEROFILL` keyword instead of the `INT` keyword. It would have avoided a lot of confusion.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Bill. But how would I go about reseting the auto increment back to zero?

Comment: Not surprisingly, this question has already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql