# Reached maximum limit of primary key and deleted all records from table but still can't insert the record

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table in which I took two field one is id that is primary key with Auto Increment attribute (tinyint) and another one is name (varchar(20)).

> `id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

after that I have insert the values in table from 1 to 127 (max limit of tinyint). Now If I try to insert the record in table it gives error because I have reached at max limit of tinyint. I am fine with it. But If I delete all the records and table is empty then also I can't insert any record. I know I can use truncate here that will reset the primary key. But My question is here that why mysql doesn't insert the any available value(from 1 to 127) for primary key and If I manually insert the value for id from 1 to 127 it works.

```
insert into `new table` (id,name) values(1,'blahblahblah')  Working

insert into `new table` (name) values('blahblahblah') Not working
```

If I have a application with large database and I come this situation and any record insertion can fail in future then how can I know before occurred this.
Is there any way by which I can insert the record(in empty table by delete all records) without truncating the table.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks

Comment: because auto_increment is not reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql saves your AUTO_INCREMENT counter in its `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table.
I don't know which version you're using but you should read the [docs about it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/2637661), you can set the number you want using

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```