# Laravel registration method do not give next available id to new user

Tags: laravel, registration

When a new user is registered through the registration form of Laravel framework, the `id` given to this new user is not the next id that exists in table `users`.

To give you an example, take a look to the next picture:

[image]

The id of the new registered user should be 6, and not 22.

What I assume is that for testing purposes I already have deleted some users from table `users` and that maybe the reason of the *gap* of ids.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: When you saying testing, do you mean you've manually created users and deleted them, or you've written unit/feature tests?

Comment: @Rwd I have manually created users and deleted them, without using the Laravel registration method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: @Rwd It worked, your answer helped me. I used the sql command 'truncate table users;' and thus the auto-increment id was reseted. Then, through the registration form, new users get correct sequent ids. I have to mention that through the 'truncate' command all data from table users were deleted. So, please take a backup before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids will not get reused, id column is using auto_increment by default

```
1 - user 1
2 - deleted
3 - deleted
4 - new user // new user will get id 4 not 2
```

if you manually delete users when doing your tests you should reset auto_increment

example with phpmyadmin

[image]

there is a AUTO_INCREMENT field you need to reset to the value you want